# Fetch database flags on CloudSQL instance using gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I want to create an replica from main PostgreSQL CloudSQL Instance.

While creating CloudSQL Instance replica, I want to apply the database flags from Main Instance to replica.

for e.g.

```
cloudsql.enable_pglogical=on, cloudsql.logical_decoding=on, max_connections=2000, log_min_duration_statement=3000, pg_stat_statements.track_utility=on, temp_file_limit=10485760, work_mem=32768, cloudsql.enable_pgaudit=on, pgaudit.log=-ddl,-all
```

I have found a way to describe the flags from the main instance.

```
gcloud sql instances describe $DATABASE_NAME
```

I have found a way to specify the `flags` as well while creating the replica.
[https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/instances/create#:~:text=must%20be%20omitted.-,%2D%2Ddatabase%2Dflags%3DFLAG%3DVALUE%2C%5BFLAG%3DVALUE%2C%E2%80%A6%5D,-Comma%2Dseparated%20list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/instances/create#:%7E:text=must%20be%20omitted.-,%2D%2Ddatabase%2Dflags%3DFLAG%3DVALUE%2C%5BFLAG%3DVALUE%2C%E2%80%A6%5D,-Comma%2Dseparated%20list)

How can I get the `flags` in comma separated way with `key=value` pairs from the main instance using `gcloud` ?

Answer (score 0):

### Get Database Flags on GCP CloudSQL

#### gcloud --format

```
CLOUDSQL_DB_FLAGS=gcloud sql instances describe $DATABASE_ID --project $PROJECT_ID --flatten="settings.databaseFlags" --format="csv(settings.databaseFlags.name, settings.databaseFlags.value)" | sed 's/,/=/' | tail -n +2 | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//'
echo $CLOUDSQL_DB_FLAGS
```

#### yq

[Install yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/v/v3.x/)(It is an utility to parse yaml data)

```
CLOUDSQL_DB_FLAGS=gcloud sql instances describe $DATABASE_ID --project $PROJECT_ID | yq ea '.settings.databaseFlags | map(.name + "=" + .value) | join(",")'
echo $CLOUDSQL_DB_FLAGS
```

Note : This will require additional installation of yq.

### Applying Flags

#### During Creation of Instance

```
gcloud sql instances create $INSTANCE_NAME --master-instance-name=$MASTER_INSTANCE_NAME --project $PROJECT_NAME --region=$REGION --availability-type=regional --no-assign-ip --network=$NETWORK --database-flags $CLOUDSQL_DB_FLAGS
```

#### After Creation of an Instance

```
gcloud sql instances patch $INSTANCE_NAME --database-flags $CLOUDSQL_DB_FLAGS --project $PROJECT_NAME
```